# Passing two different property values to a method

Tags: c#

I have two different properties and hence two values.  These properties are read and write properties.  I have one method and I need to pass both property values to this one method.  How to I accomplish this?  Is using Array the only way to do this?
Here is example:

In a Calculator example:

```
//Property 1
public int numberone
{
 get { return passnumberone; }
 set { passnumberone = Add(value);}
}
//Property 2
public int numbertwo
{
 get { return passnumbertwo; }
 set { passnumbertwo = Add(value);}
 }
//Method
private int Add(?)
{
int numberone
int numbertwo
int finalanswer
finalanswer = numberone + numbertwo
return finalanswer;
}
//Calling 
Calculator.numberone = 10;
Calculator.numbertwo = 12;
```

I know I could use the method only and pass these two number very easily.  But I am trying to use the porperties.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. Why are the setters calling a method at all? What are you trying to achieve? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I appologize, I should be more clear.  I am a beginner in c# programming and trying to understand the concept of encapsulation.  I am using the Calculator example to pass two parameters to a method.

Comment: I have two classes, First one calls the second as an object.  The second one has two properties and a method.  I know there are easier ways to handle this particular example of adding two numbers.  But I am trying to understand how to pass two paramters to a method.

Comment: "First one calls the second as an object" doesn't make sense. Please try to be very precise in what you're saying. Passing two arguments to a method is easy, but it's much hard to work out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let me give it another try - I have two classes, similar to what deepee1 is stating in his answer. First class has input values. Second class conducts the calculator operation or addition. I pass the values (numbers) to the second class, which has the two properties and a method (see my example above).

Comment: But what do you expect the result of setting those properties to be? And why aren't you just calling a method afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass the object that contains the properties to the method if the object is not the same as the one that contains the Add method.

```
class CalculatorInputs
{
  public int numberone;
  public int numbertwo;
}

class CalculatorOperations
{
  public int Add(CalculatorInputs input)
  {
    return input.numberone + input.numbertwo;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both values to the method as parameters:

```
private int Add(int numberone, int numbertwo)
{
    int finalanswer
    finalanswer = numberone + numbertwo
    return finalanswer;
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
int answer = this.Add(numberone, numbertwo);
```

But to be honest your first question contradicts your second, also, you shouldn't be calling this everytime you set a number, seems kind of confusing to me, and there's probably a better way to do it, but I'm insure of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the properties beforehand calling the method, you don't have to pass anything to the method.

```
private int Add()
{
    int finalanswer;
    finalanswer = this.numberone + this.numbertwo
    return finalanswer;
}
```

and you can call

```
Calculator c = new Calculator();
c.numberOne = 10;
c.numberTwo = 12;
int sum = c.Add();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are upto here but in any case you would be needing a Third property which will actually give you the Added value;

So need of calling the Add method at all

```
public int AddedNumber
{
 get { return passnumberone + passnumbertwo ; } 
}
```

If this is not what you intend then please expand and add more details to your question.